# Avoid React Ajax + FileUpload + FormData to refresh page after success

Tags: ajax, reactjs

I don't know why but after an AjaxCall with formData+files_upload, the entire page is reloaded. 
This doesn't happen with normal Ajax Call.

I have no FORM tag or something as you know if you use REACT.

I have an inline file-upload component to load async file.

```
<FlatButton label="Upload File" onClick = { (e) => this.commonUploadFile(e) } />
```

The trigger is simple.

The method:

```
 e.preventDefault(); // Let's stop this event.
        e.stopPropagation(); // Really this time.

        let formData = new FormData();
        const file = files[0]; //passed by wrapping method
        formData.append('uploading_file', file);
        formData.append('file_name',this.state.file_name);
        formData.append('original_filename',this.state.original_filename);
        formData.append('userToken',window.userToken);
        formData.append('file_path',this.props.attributes.dirname);

        $.ajax({
            method: 'POST',
            data: formData,
            cache: false,
            contentType: false,
            processData: false,
            async : true,
            url: process.env.REACT_APP_FILE_UPLOAD,
            complete: function(result){
                result = JSON.parse(result.responseText);
                this.setState({upload_result : result.success});
            }.bind(this),
          });

          return false;
```

The call end successfully and the state of component are changed properly but after that, the entire site refresh and I don't know why.

Answer (score 1):

I've finally find out the problem.
When using a developing server (npm start) any filesystem change will launch a page refresh and a file upload change the file system.

So pay attention.